# Making text easily copyable in an HTML E-mail without extra blank characters

Tags: html, email, twig, html-email

I am having trouble formatting the password reset e-mail for my users so that the password can be easily copied without any extra characters, blank or otherwise.

So far I have tried the following formats. I use TWIG, if you are unfamiliar everything inside of the double curly brackets is a variable. Whitespace is not counted inside these brackets.

**Attempt 1**

```
You requested a password reset for your account {{ user.username }}.
<br /><br />
Your password has been reset to: {{ password }}
<br />
<br />
Please keep track of your new password and follow <a href="{{ url('index') }}">this link to login</a>
```

**Attempt 2**

```
You requested a password reset for your account {{ user.username }}.
<br /><br />
Your password has been reset to:
<br />
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ password }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</br />
Please keep track of your new password and follow <a href="{{ url('index') }}">this link to login</a>
```

In both of these cases I am getting an extra blank character when I paste the password after copying it.

Comment: Have you tried putting the BR directly behind the password, instead of on the next line? `… {{ password }}<br>`

Comment: This comment is actually the way to do it. If you put the <br> on the same line, it is way easier to only select the password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting the BR directly behind the password, instead of on the next line:

```
… {{ password }}<br>
```

It is presumably the white space (line break) that causes trouble when copy&pasting the value.